# What is the most difficult operation in binary trees?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have investigated this BSTs and found answer in [Algorithms, Part I](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) lectures.
As mentioned in lectures delete is the most difficult operation in terms of implementation and in terms of efficiency.

[image]

But this only for simple binary trees.
What about Red-Black BSTs and another?

Comment: this question seems purely academic, are you trying to solve an actual problem here?

Comment: @SpliFF I'm more interested in practical side, not in theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a BST ([Binary-Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)) both Search and Insert works in `O(log n)`,

since they work the same way ..

Deletion take `O(T(Search) + T(Delete-Node)) = O(T(Search) + T(Find-Ancestor) + C)`

`= O(log n + d)` where d is tree height ..